# When we install Internal Beta version app then it production version getting installed

Tags: android, google-play-console

The internal users are trying to install the beta version(version 1.1.1) of the app for internal testing from play store. The production version(version 1.1.2) is getting installed instead of Beta version. On Play store the app is shown as Internal Beta, but when user is clicking on install button, it's downloading the production app.
So, help us out.

did not find any solution till now.

Comment: The production version is newer than the beta version? Typically your beta version will be newer (have a higher version name/code).

Answer (score 1):

Play Store will install the highest version code that your are eligible to.

In your case, the app version in production has a higher version so that one will be installed, even if you're eligible for beta.